# Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus - change from release to stable channel

Tags: release-management, 16.04

Last week I installed a desktop and thought I should install Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus right away. That would prevent a later upgrade. As I understand in these last weeks nothing really changes, it's mostly testing.

Now I would like to know if I need to change the channel from RC (release) to stable, or if this happens automatically? How can I check this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to change anything.

If you want you can check the package sources in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

All lines that don't start with a `#` should have something with `xenial` in the third field (after the URL), for example

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
```

or

```
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
```